# probability with Guassian mixture Model

Tags: matlab, classification

I have two class with label
I want to classify with Gaussian Mixture Model in matlab
but I don't Know how to calculate probability my test data for two class

```
clear all
clc

train_class0_data = load('train-class0.data');
train_class0_label = load('train-class0.label');
train_class1_data = load('train-class1.data');
train_class1_label = load('train-class1.label');
test_data = load('test.data');
test_label = load('test.label');

GMMObject_Class0 = gmdistribution.fit(train_class0_data,2,'Regularize',0.001,'SharedCov', true,'CovType','diagonal' );
Probability_Class0 = posterior(GMMObject_Class0, test_data);

GMMObject_Class1 = gmdistribution.fit(train_class1_data,2,'Regularize',0.001,'SharedCov', true,'CovType','diagonal' );
Probability_Class1 = posterior(GMMObject_Class1, test_data);
```

Please guide me that how to calculate Probability?

Comment: Shouldn't you use [`pdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.pdf.html) instead of `posterior` here?