# How to classsify with Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM)

Tags: matlab, classification

I'm using GMM in matlab for data classification.

The problem is similiar to this question: [probability with Guassian mixture Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347215/probability-with-guassian-mixture-model)

I have the following datasets:

```
trainData1; % dataset for class 1
trainData2; % dataset for class 2
testData; % test dataset
```

To obtain the GMM models:

```
GMM_class1=gmdistribution.fit(trainData1,12,'CovType','diagonal');
GMM_class2=gmdistribution.fit(trainData2,12,'CovType','diagonal');
```

To obtain the log-likeihood for test dataset for each class:

```
[posteriorTest_Train1,nlogL_1]=posterior(GMM_class1,testData);
[posteriorTest_Train2,nlogL_2]=posterior(GMM_class2,testData);
```

To classify, I'm doing this:

```
if nlogL_1 < nlogL_2
    % testData belongs to class 1
else
    % testData belongs to class 2
end
```

Please, I'd like to know if I'm doing it correctly.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the gmm that I understand. 
If you intend to classify whether an item belongs to class 1 or classs 2,
then I would do the following.

```
GMM_class = gmdistribution.fit(trainData,2,'CovType','diagonal');
posteriorTest = posterior(GMM_class,testData);
```

Then you could perform the if statement to judge if the test data belongs to class 1 or class 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't understand the difference. When I use GMM_class1 and GMM_class2 I intend to obtain the model of each class. Isn't it right? Considering your answer, I'm undertanding that you have all train dataset (trainData1 and trainData2) in a only one set (trainData), right? Thus, how can I perform the if statement in this way?

Comment: The posterior should has two values, one is for class 1 and the other is for class 2. The you just choose the big one as the label.

Comment: I think you're thinking this: the gmdistribution.fit function is gmdistribution.fit(X,k), where X is the data set and k is the number of classes. But, in my understanding, k is the number of components (gaussians) used to model one class.

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding. I think gmm is more like a unsupervised method.